# JSON parsing error in ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am using `NSJSONSerialization` for parsing a JSON response from an API call.
However am getting a error all the time saying

> (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and
>   option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0xde41760
>   {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and
>   option to allow fragments not set.}

This is what I am using for parsing a JSON on iOS side

```
NSArray * myArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                options:kNilOptions
                                                  error:&error2];
```

This is my JSON response am getting from API call

```
[
{
    "23456": {
        "status": 0,
        "type": "web/http-server",
        "link": "https://app.te345.com/web/http-server?testId=23456",
        "name": "Server A\""
    }
 }
 ]
```

I have validated the JSON it shows valid JSON.

If I changed the options in `NSJSONSerializer` am getting the

```
Invalid value around character 1
```

I searched for solutions in Google but didn't help much, any inputs on this will be of great help as am struck with this for quite long now.

Comment: The JSON in your question is missing a } before the ].  Is this a paste error or this actually what you have received from the server?

Comment: Missing a "," after ` "name": "Server A\""`, a missing "}", etc.. Your JSON is not valid, or at least, not the one you paste. Tested on: http://jsonlint.com

Comment: @Larme it is not necessary to have the extra "," there. @Paulw11 is correct, only `}` is missing.

Comment: It is just a paste error sorry for that i edited the question

Comment: The JSON appears valid as edited.  Your problem is likely some unprintable character at the start of the string.  NSLog your `data` object and examine the characters.  Also, if you are converting from NSString to NSData, make sure you're using the UTF8 conversion mode.

Comment: I did that already but data looks fine. you can look at the data here http://pastebin.com/fmp2SJUx. I am not converting from NSString to NSData using the NSData directly

Comment: You can see from the pastebin that the first character is a new line - 0x0a. You need to fix your server code so that this is not sent

Comment: @Paulw11 I was able to solve the problem as you said there were some unwanted characters were from the response i removed it and starting working.Thanks all for your help